# What to do in this kind of "dipped curve" situation?

Tags: waveform

What to do in this kind of "dipped curve" situation?

[image]

It's not audible as something weird, nor is there a particular change in amplitude. But it looks weird.

Comment: It looks like you've got one massive bass frequency in there, that you might not even be able to hear. Can you run a graphical tool on it to see? Or post it so we can hear it?

Comment: That might not be audible on regular speakers, but I bet that would give you something you could feel on a powerful sub. The wavelength is roughly double the length of that dip and could have been caused by wind or something banging into the mic/pick-up/able. This particular wave looks like it has offset the normal sound toward rarefaction. On a large speaker, you would be able to see the cone pull inwards while still vibrating normally.  This probably won't affect the sound on good speakers but may cause the cone to bottom out on lower-quality speakers.

Answer (score 1):

This is some large amplitude oscillation with frequency much lower than the rest of the signal. As you show no timescale, it's impossible to estimate its frequency. Also, you don't give any context, so it's difficult to say more about it.

Low frequencies can be removed with appropriately set high pass filter and there might be benefits to do so. Such oscillation may unnecessarily trigger a compressor, limiter, or other dynamic processor. They also reduce headroom in the mix.

On the other hand, any kind of signal processing may have negative impact on the sound, so while high pass filter is a commonly used tool, you should check the results critically.